# Using Groupby with Duplicated

Tags: duplicates, multiple-columns, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have researched this and not found any information to do the following. I need to

1. groupby a set of columns (here: studentid, subj, topic, lesson).
2. Then I need to find the duplicated rows in a subset of columns
   (here: testtime, responsetime).
3. Create a column that indicates whether the row (across the 2 columns) is a duplicate or not

**Starting dataframe**

```
   studentid   subj   topic  lesson  testtime    responsetime
1  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec
2  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec
3  1           math   add    a       timestamp2  30sec
4  1           math   add    a       timestamp3  15sec
5  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec
6  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec
7  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec
8  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec
```

**What I have tried: 
Method 1:**
 Using putting duplicated in a user-defined function to create a column indicating whether the row is a duplicate or not - ERROR: 'function' object is not subscriptable

```
def check_dup(list):
    return df.duplicated([list],keep='first')

df_alt['dup_values'] = df.groupby(['studentidd', 'subj','topic','lesson']). apply(check_dup['testtime','responsetime'],axis=1)
```

**Method 2:** 
Using multiindexing, but the problem there is that the duplicated function is looking for duplicates in the index rows, and not in a separate column set ('testtime','responsetime'):

```
  dfnew['dup_indicator'] = df.set_index(['studentidd', 'subj','topic','lesson']).
duplicated(['testtime','responsetime'],keep=False)
```

**Desired dataframe**

```
   studentid   subj   topic  lesson  testtime   responsetime dup_indicator
1  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec             1
2  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec             1
3  1           math   add    a       timestamp2  30sec             0
4  1           math   add    a       timestamp3  15sec             0
5  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec              1 
6  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec              1
7  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec             1
8  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `groupby` or modify the index to accomplish what you want to do.  Just pass in all the columns that you want to use to identify as duplicates:

```
> df
    studentid   subj    topic   lesson  testtime    responsetime
1   1           math    add     a       timestamp1  45sec
2   1           math    add     a       timestamp1  45sec
3   1           math    add     a       timestamp2  30sec
4   1           math    add     a       timestamp3  15sec
5   1           math    add     b       timestamp1  0sec
6   1           math    add     b       timestamp1  0sec
7   1           math    add     b       timestamp1  45sec
8   1           math    add     b       timestamp1  45sec

> dup_cols = ['studentid', 'subj', 'topic', 'lesson', 'testtime', 'responsetime']
> df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=dup_cols, keep=False), 'dup_indicator'] = 1
> df['dup_indicator'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
> df

    studentid   subj    topic   lesson  testtime    responsetime    dup_indicator
1   1       math        add     a       timestamp1  45sec           1.0
2   1       math        add     a       timestamp1  45sec           1.0
3   1       math        add     a       timestamp2  30sec           0.0
4   1       math        add     a       timestamp3  15sec           0.0
5   1       math        add     b       timestamp1  0sec            1.0
6   1       math        add     b       timestamp1  0sec            1.0
7   1       math        add     b       timestamp1  45sec           1.0
8   1       math        add     b       timestamp1  45sec           1.0
```

To break down the steps:

- Find all rows where `df.duplicated` returns `True`, in this case all rows that are duplicates based on what's passed to the `subset` argument
- Filter the dataframe to select the duplicate rows using `.loc`
- Creating a new column `dup_indicator` and assigning `1` to the duplicate rows
- Use `fillna` to assign `0` to the non-duplicate rows

Comment: This worked really nicely! And it was a much simpler solution to what I had been envisioning.

Comment: One follow-up ques -- when I want to keep just one, I add keep='first', but the value_counts still assigns df['dup_indicator] ==1 for both duplicated rows. How do I create a df keeing just 'first' of the duplicated rows.

Comment: If you don't need an indicator column, you can just use the following: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=dup_cols)`.  The default behavior is to keep the first of the duplicate rows